# Keep selected rows when dismissing UITableViewController - Swift, UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Does anyone know how to keep the rows selected/highlighed in UITableView when you move from a new View Controller back to your UITableView?

When I make a selection and dismiss the table view controller, the selection is no longer there when I return. I set clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear to false inside `super.viewDidLoad` but that didn't work, someone on StackOverflow mentioned doing the following:

```
class TableViewController:
UITableViewController,
UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var drugTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    }


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

let indexPaths = self.drugTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath]

self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPaths, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

}
```

but that won't compile due to this error:

`self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPaths, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)`

Cannot convert the expression's type '(indexPath: [AnyObject]?, animated: BooleanLiteralConvertible, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)' to type 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

Could someone help me out with this one, this is such a headache.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're dismissing your table view controller, when you come back, you're coming to a new instance of your table view controller, so it's not going to know anything about your selections. If you want to go back to the same instance, you need to keep a strong pointer to it in the controller before it, and only instantiate a new one the first time you go to it.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I do that? Sorry, I'm very new to swift.

Comment: Not sure how to code a strong pointer and only instantiate a tableview 1 time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save selected rows when dismissing UITableViewController - Swift, UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094158/save-selected-rows-when-dismissing-uitableviewcontroller-swift-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to false on your table view controller.

Comment: what sort of transition are you making? are performing a segue? Are you the presenting or the presented view controller?

Comment: I'm performing a modal segue from the Storyboard

Comment: ctrl dragged from a static cell in the previous ViewController to the TableViewController.... http://imgur.com/LrJQ9YB